# Drupal update.php on Azure throws error "Could not connect to server"

Tags: php, azure, ssl, drupal, drupal-7

For migrating D7.3 to D7.42 completed the normal steps. Post that run /update.php.

1. => Requirements verifications was okay
2. => Overview stage instructions in place
3. => Review updates "Runs for 2-3 minutes" and then throws back error as below:

Could not connect to server
Overview:
Could not connect to abc.azurewebsites.net .
Details:
Peer disconnected after first handshake message: Possibly SSL/TLS Protocol    level is too low or unsupported on the server

URL formed in browser even during the error is as below:-
    https://abc.azurewebsites.net/update.php?op=selection&token=JYkvAlNOkbWlBmj8BFRDrUlWmFXmZIysqgXO9ZzUjNs

Other Details

```
=> Azure Subscription  
=> To Scale, Kept instance count to 3/ Pricing Tier to standard / Instance size to medium 2 cores.  
=> First time, I run, I got the Review updates stage with 2 database columns alteration message listed and applied it. After few couple of attempts, I also got the message "No Pending updates" and link to front and admin sites.  
=> In Settings.php, $update_free_access = TRUE was kept for update run.
```

Query:

1. Am curious to know why this Peer disconnected message came in
   between the attempts?
   b. Is it because of my SSL using TLS1.2? How to avoid this in future?

Comment: Do you follow this guide https://www.drupal.org/node/1494290 to update your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow the official guide at https://www.drupal.org/node/1494290 to upgrade Drupal from 7.3x to 7.42, which works fine on my side. Also I cannot reproduce your issue here.

And there some points we should pay attention to during the updating.

1. make sure to set the site on maintenance mode
2. Delete all the files & folders inside your original Drupal instance except for /sites (do not delete `web.config` as well on Azure). Which should be in `D:\home\site\wwwroot` on Azure Web Apps.
3. Copy all the folders and files except /sites from inside the extracted Drupal package [tar ball or zip package] into your original Drupal instance location. On Azure, we can login KUDU console site of your Web Apps Service and directly copy the zip package to the file list table to automatically upload and extract the zip to Azure.
4. Login to your site as administrator and Run `update.php`.

As a workaround, you can upgrade your site on locally, and with the database connection info to the MySQL Service on Azure. Then deploy your new Drupal site to Azure.